# Add numbers with same text together

Tags: batch-file

I would like to create a batch file in which I can see what I have collected in a game.
The game saves this information in a .txt file.
The output would look like this.

```
70x Silver.
Back Pearl.
41x Copper.
Amethyst.
Amethyst.
12x Silver.
Back Pearl.
21x Copper.
5x Silver.
Back Pearl.
Back Pearl.
Amethyst.
```

What I want to do now, is to add the items with the same name together, like this:

```
128x Silver.
4x Back Pearl.
62x Copper.
3x Amethyst.
```

There are hundreds of items with different names, not just these 4.
Would that be possible?
Any help would be appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

`Would that be possible?` - Yes.

```
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
for /f "delims=" %%a in (t.txt) do (
  set " z=%%a"
  set " z=!z:x =@!"
  set " z=!z: =_!"
  for /f "tokens=1,2 delims=@" %%b in ("!z!") do (
    if "%%c" == "" (
      set "x=1"
      set "y=%%b
    ) else (
      set "x=%%b"
      set "y=%%c"
    )
    set /a #!y!+=!x!
  )
)
(for /f "tokens=1,2 delims=#=" %%a in ('set #') do (
  set "x=%%a"
  set "y=%%bx    "
  echo !y:~0,4! !x:_= !
))>summary.txt
```

Output with your example data (I hope, alphabetic sorting is ok for you):

```
3x Amethyst.
4x Back Pearl.
62x Copper.
87x Silver.
```

(your calculation of 120 silver might be a bit optimistic with the given input data)

Comment: I was about to give up at first, but thank you, thank you, thank you! It works perfectly!
Optimistic is better than pessimistic. :D

Comment: With data line `Pollux Infusion` delivers `0x Infusion`

Comment: @Magoo: ah, the `x<space>`, I used as delimiter. Didn't think of that.

Comment: Is there a way to line up the text?
I've tried, but I just can't figure out how. @Stephan

Comment: No big deal. I adapted both my answers for aligning (you might need to adapt the spacing according to how big your numbers may get)

Answer (score 1):

```
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL
rem The following settings for the source directory and filename are names
rem that I use for testing and deliberately include names which include spaces to make sure
rem that the process works using such names. These will need to be changed to suit your situation.

SET "sourcedir=u:\your files"
SET "filename1=%sourcedir%\q72672485.txt"

:: remove variables starting #
FOR  /F "delims==" %%b In ('set # 2^>Nul') DO SET "%%b="

FOR /f "usebackqdelims=" %%b IN ("%filename1%") DO (
 CALL :sub %%b
)
SETLOCAL ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION 
(
FOR  /F "tokens=1,2delims==" %%b In ('set # 2^>Nul') DO (
 SET "line=%%cx%%b"
 ECHO !line:#= !
)
)>summary.txt
endlocal
type summary.txt
GOTO :EOF

:sub
SET "quantity=%1"
SET "line=%*"
IF /i "%quantity:~-1%"=="x" (SET /a quantity=%quantity:~0,-1%&SET "line=%line:* =%") ELSE SET quantity=1
IF %quantity%==0 SET /a quantity=1&SET "line=%*"
SET /a #%line: =#%+=quantity
GOTO :eof
```

Different approach...

Comment: Standardize the input line before processing. Nice.

Answer (score 1):

Another one!

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion

for /F "delims=" %%l in (test.txt) do for /F "tokens=1*" %%a in ("%%l") do (
   set "first=%%a"
   if "!first:~-1!" equ "x" (set /A "num=!first:~0,-1!") else set "num=0"
   if !num! equ 0 (
      set "rest=%%l"
      set /A "count[!rest: =_!]+=1"
   ) else (
      set "rest=%%b"
      set /A "count[!rest: =_!]+=num"
   )
)

(for /F "tokens=2* delims=[]=" %%a in ('set count[') do (
   set "item=%%a"
   if %%b equ 1 (
      echo !item:_= !
   ) else (
      echo %%bx !item:_= !
   )
)) > summary.txt
```

Comment: suppresses the `1x`, like in the original file. I personally don't like it, but it may be what OP wants.

Comment: @Stephan: Yes, I think so...

Answer (score 0):

Another approach (splitting the file into items with and without quantity) (also fixing the `Pollux Infusion` issue in my first answer):

```
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
REM process lines without quantity:
for /f "delims=" %%a in ('type test.txt^|findstr /vrc:"[0123456789][0123456789]*x "') do call :count 1 "%%a"
REM process lines with quantity:
for /f "tokens=1*delims=x " %%a in ('type test.txt^|findstr /rc:"[0123456789][0123456789]*x "') do call :count %%a "%%b"
REM reformat:
(for /f "tokens=1,2 delims=#=" %%a in ('set #') do (
  set "count=%%bx     "
  set "line=!count:~0,5!%%a"           &REM including '1x'
   if %%b==1 set "line=     %%a"       &REM supressing '1x'
  echo !line:_= !
))>summary.txt
type summary.txt
goto :eof

:count
set item=%~2
set "item=%item: =_%"
set /a #%item% +=%1
```

Included both with and without `1x`. Remove the line, you don't want.

Answer (score 0):

This is a different approach that use a "file merge" method. The overall code is somewhat simpler than other methods...

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion

set "lineNum=0"
(for /F "tokens=1,2* delims=:x " %%a in ('(type test.txt ^& echo 0x^) ^| findstr /N "[0-9][0-9]*x"') do (
   if !lineNum! lss %%a call :locateLine %%a
   set "line=%%c"
   set /A "count[!line: =_!]+=%%b"
)) < test.txt 
set "count[="

(for /F "tokens=2* delims=[]=" %%a in ('set count[') do (
   set "item=%%a"
   if %%b equ 1 (echo !item:_= !) else echo %%bx !item:_= !
)) > summary.txt

goto :EOF


:locateLine num
set /A "lineNum+=1" & set /P "line=" & if errorlevel 1 exit /B
if %lineNum% lss %1 set /A "count[%line: =_%]+=1" & goto locateLine
exit /B
```